# Remove / customize facets borders in tmap (tm_facets)

Tags: r, border, facet, tmap

I created a plot with multiple facets, thanks to tmap (R package) and tm_facets.

I would like to remove the borders of the facets titles (i.e. the black rectangles on top of each map), but I can't figure out how.

Here is an example:

```
library(tmap)

data(World, NLD_muni, NLD_prov, land, metro)

current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")

tm_shape(NLD_prov) +
  tm_polygons("gold2") +
  tm_facets(by="name")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try yo use *frame.lwd = NA* and optional *panel.label.bg.color = NA* to remove the background colour in the facetbox

```
    library(tmap)

    data(World, NLD_muni, NLD_prov, land, metro)

    current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")

    tm_shape(NLD_prov) +
      tm_polygons("gold2") +
      tm_facets(by="name") +
      tm_layout(frame = FALSE, frame.lwd = NA, panel.label.bg.color = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set that parameter, and many others in the tm_layout() function. In this case just set the frame argument to be false

```
library(tmap)

data(World, NLD_muni, NLD_prov, land, metro)

current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")

tm_shape(NLD_prov) +
  tm_polygons("gold2") +
  tm_facets(by="name") +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
However, this code removes the borders of the "maps", whereas I want to remove the borders of each "title". Do you have any idea how to do that ?